# Как сделать документацию для всего модуля Pyhon?

Tags: python, документация

К примеру, в начале функции можно написать что-то в кавычках и при вызове `help` на этой функции
К примеру:

```
def foo():
  "Бесполезная функция"
   ...


help(foo) # Бесполезная функция и ещё доп. информация
```

Вопрос: Можно ли так сделать для самого модуля? Т.е. для всего файла. И если да, то как его потом вызывать?

Comment: https://realpython.com/documenting-python-code/

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/